# How can I create a 'share to Facebook button' in a SpriteKit game using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, function, sprite-kit

I have made a simple game using the Game template in Xcode, coded in swift. I created a shapeNode, and when it is touched, I would like this code to run:

```
        if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook){
            var controller = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
            controller.setInitialText("Testing Posting to Facebook")
            //self.presentViewController(controller, animated:true, completion:nil)
        }
```

This code is run in the GameViewController.swift file, but gives this error. This error occurs on the commented line.

```
Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x379480d0) to 'SKView' (0x37227ad0).
```

Comment: Where ***exactly*** does the error occur?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25595601/swift-spritekit-facebook-share-button

Comment: Also, I have tried the possible duplicate, and the error persists.

Comment: @boidkan that doesn't really tell me how to solve that error. Nor does it give me a way of posting to Facebook from inside the app. But thank you.

Comment: @luk2302 the line that is commented out has the error. Sorry for not being specific :)

Comment: What's the type of 'self'?

Comment: In case you are interested, I updated my answer you marked as correct. I slightly changed the helper to now use swift 2 protocol extensions which makes using it a little bit nicer. Check it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: If you are targeting iOS 9 or above there are some small changes to make this work. You will need to add the correct URL schemes to your info.plist otherwise the check to see if the app is installed will not work.

NOTE: Its is a better idea to now use UIActivityController for sharing. This allows you to only use 1 button and you can share to all sorts of services.

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/querying-url-schemes-with-canopenurl/

To present a viewController in a SKScene you need to use the rootViewController

```
self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(...
```

I use a little helper for this using swift 2 protocol extensions, so you can use it anywhere you like in your app. The Facebook part looks like this, twitter is basically the same.

```
import SpriteKit
import Social

/// URLString
private struct URLString {
    static let iTunesApp = URL(string: "Your iTunes app link")
    static let facebookApp = URL(string: "Your Facebook app link")
    static let facebookWeb = URL(string: "Your Facebook web link")
}

/// Text strings
private struct TextString {
    static let shareSheetText = "Your share sheet text"
    static let error = "Error"
    static let enableSocial = "Please sign in to your account first"
    static let settings = "Settings"
    static let ok = "OK"
}

/// Social
protocol Social {}
extension Social where Self: SKScene {

/// Open facebook
func openFacebook() {
    guard let facebookApp = URLString.facebookApp else { return }
    guard let facebookWeb = URLString.facebookWeb else { return }

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(facebookApp){     
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(facebookApp)
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(facebookWeb)
    }
}

/// Share to facebook
func shareToFacebook() {

    guard SLComposeViewController.isAvailable(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook) else {
        showAlert()
        return
    }

    guard let facebookSheet = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook) else { return }
    facebookSheet.completionHandler = { result in

        switch result {

        case .cancelled:
            print("Facebook message cancelled")
            break

        case .done:
            print("Facebook message complete")
            break
        }
    }

    let text = TextString.shareSheetText
    //facebookSheet.setInitialText(text)
    facebookSheet.setInitialText(String.localizedStringWithFormat(text, "add your score property")) // same as line above but with a score property
    facebookSheet.addImage(Your UIImage)
    facebookSheet.add(URLString.iTunesApp)

    self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.present(facebookSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

   // MARK: - Private Methods

   /// Show alert
   private func showAlert() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: TextString.error, message: TextString.enableSocial, preferredStyle: .alert)

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: TextString.ok, style: .cancel) { _ in }
    alertController.addAction(okAction)

    let settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: TextString.settings, style: .default) { _ in

        if let url = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    }
    alertController.addAction(settingsAction)

    self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

To use the helper you simply go to the SKScene you need to call the methods and implement the protocol

```
 class YourScene: SKScene, Social {....
```

Now when the Facebook node/button is pressed you can call the methods as if they are part of the scene itself.

```
openFacebook()    // opens app or safari
shareToFacebook() // opens share sheet textField
```

all thanks to swift 2 and protocol extensions. The cool bit about this is say you want to use this helper in a regular UIKit app, than all you have to do is import UIKit instead of spriteKit

```
 import UIKit
```

and change the protocol extension to this

```
 extension Social where Self: UIViewController {....
```

Its quite nice and very flexible I think

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, I will update this later today. I would actually recommend that you use UIActivityController for your sharing from now on. This way you only need 1 sharing button and you can share to all sorts of sites. There is plenty tutorials available.

Comment: Updated to Swift 3. I still recommend you have a look at UIActivityController. Happy coding

Comment: Thanks for recommendations:) Recently did this with UIActivityController. Easy and the better way. Best wishes!

Comment: Yeah, UIActivityController very nice and quite easy to use. Happy coding