# How to create reusable UIAlertcontroller?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uialertcontroller

I want to create a reusable UIAlertController class for my project.I tried the following code.But my alert is not showing.What is the wrong in my code or any code help.This is my alert class

```
class AlertView: NSObject {

 class func showAlert(view: UIViewController , message: String){

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        view.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

and i am calling this in my another view controller like

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      AlertView.showAlert(self, message: "Test alert")
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   }
}
```

Comment: try once in button action

Comment: `viewDidLoad()` might be to early, try to put it in `viewDidAppear()` instead.

Comment: else try in viewdidAppear..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

present your alert in `main_queue`

```
class AlertView: NSObject {

    class func showAlert(view: UIViewController , message: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            view.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        AlertView.showAlert(self, message: "Test alert")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at my answer if you would like a slightly Swiftier solution.

Answer (score 8):

You can use Anbu Karthiks answer. As an alternative I use Swift 2s protocol extensions to show alerts.

```
import UIKit

protocol Alertable { }
extension Alertable where Self: UIViewController {

func showAlert(title title: String, message: String) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel) { _ in }
    alertController.addAction(okAction)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {       
       self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

 func showAlertWithSettings(title title: String, message: String) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel) { _ in }
    alertController.addAction(okAction)

    let settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .Default) { _ in
       guard let url = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) else { return }
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
    alertController.addAction(settingsAction)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {       
         self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

Now in your viewControllers where you need to show alerts you simply conform to the protocol

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, Alertable { }
```

and call the methods like

```
showAlert(title: "Alert title", message: "Alert message")
```

as if they are part of the viewController itself.

[Swift SpriteKit: Best practice to access UIViewController in GameScene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35875674/swift-spritekit-best-practice-to-access-uiviewcontroller-in-gamescene/35894178#35894178)

Note: As members have said in the comments, viewDidLoad might be to soon to show an alert. Try using a slight delay or ViewDidAppear

Hope this helps

Comment: Voting up for protocol extension approach with Swift 2.x

Answer (score 0):

**REUSABLE ALERT in swift 3&4**

```
class AlertView: NSObject {
    class func showAlert(view: UIViewController , title: String , message: String){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        view.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

 //How to use?
 //Alert.showAlert(view: self, title: "Alert!", message: "Reusable Alert")
```